# The phrase "wiping out " meaning in this context?

Tags: phrases, word-in-context

here is a slight problem with the skate park that you designed. Beginning skateboarders keep **wiping out** on one section of hills that are a bit difficult to navigate.

The solution you have come up with is to place a board over the two humps to **flatten out** the section where skaters are wiping out. You have a longboard, but you need to determine what length to cut it. To do this, you must identify the two points that the board will touch when you lay it across the valley. "

I am not too sure what it means by wiping out and flatten out in this context. My guess is that "**wiping out** " here means the longboard exceed the distance between the top tips of the two humps, but then "**flatten out**" seems to contradict my guess.

Thank you very much for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

In skating, surfing, biking, and other sports, to *wipe out* is to crash or fall. The problem is supposing that there is a place in the skate park where slayers often fall off their skate boards.

In general, to flatten something out means to make it more flat. They are proposing to make the skate park safer by making a bumpy area flatter.

Comment: Big thanks, now I understand the paragraph is saying that adding a layer to fill out between humps to flatten out places where trip the skateboarders.